# Conexión a Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2007

Tengo un programa de escritorio que tiene una base de datos access. Quiero vincular está base de datos con otra MySQL en mi servidor remoto.
La vinculación de las tablas es correcta, pero desde que vínculo las dos el programa no funciona.
Alguien sabe porque???
Me arroja un error 364 (objeto de ha descargado). Esto ocurre cuando la base de datos access tiene las tablas vinculadas, si no las tiene vinculadas no aparece el error y el.prohrama funciona correctamente.
Disculpar mis explicaciones, confieso que he puesto el post rápido y desde el móvil, en un momento de agobio.
Gracias a todos

Comment: Échale un vistazo al apartado cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "No funciona no es una buena descripción de lo que pasa". [Te podrían votar negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción, error o comportamiento incorrecto.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877/)

Comment: Hay algun error? tira algun mensaje? que es lo que pasa exactamente? Si necesitas agregar informacion a tu pregunta usa el boton [edit]